# Django Nested Groups: Groups in Groups

Tags: django, django-authentication

In Django (when using django.contrib.auth) may I add a `Group` to another `Group`? Ie a a `Group` be a member of another `Group`?

If so how do I do this? I add `User`s to a `Group` using the `user_set`, but from what I gather the default `Group` model does not have a many to many to it self.

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#groups

Comment: There is a solution in django-mptt documentation: http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/models.html#registration-of-existing-models

Comment: The django-mptt documentation url has changed: https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html#registration-of-existing-models

Answer (score 3):

## django-groups-manager

This can be done using `django-groups-manager`:

- Documentation: https://django-groups-manager.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
- GitHub: https://github.com/vittoriozamboni/django-groups-manager
- PyPi: https://pypi.org/project/django-groups-manager/

The following is taken from the documentation. It shows creating a group called 'F.C. Internazionale Milan', then adding 'Staff' and 'Players' sub-groups, then finally adding members to those groups.

```py
from groups_manager.models import Group, Member
fc_internazionale = Group.objects.create(name='F.C. Internazionale Milan')
staff = Group.objects.create(name='Staff', parent=fc_internazionale)
players = Group.objects.create(name='Players', parent=fc_internazionale)
thohir = Member.objects.create(first_name='Eric', last_name='Thohir')
staff.add_member(thohir)
palacio = Member.objects.create(first_name='Rodrigo', last_name='Palacio')
players.add_member(palacio)
```

## django-mptt

Note that, although the `django-group-manager` package appears to be actively maintained, this package is based on the [`django-mptt`](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) package, which is marked as **unmaintained** on the GitHub project.

As mentioned in a previous comment, the `django-mptt` package may also help implement this functionality.

The documentation provides an example that shows adding a `parent` attribute to the `Group` auth model.

https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html#registration-of-existing-models

```py
import mptt
from mptt.fields import TreeForeignKey
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

# add a parent foreign key
TreeForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True).contribute_to_class(Group, 'parent')

mptt.register(Group, order_insertion_by=['name'])
```

Answer (score 2):

The native Django doesn't provide this opportunity.